# SELECT DISTINCT TWO columns not ranged

Tags: distinct

How can I select distinct two columns not ranged correctly. 
for example: 
if I have this table t:

```
================
|| a   || b   ||
=======||=======
|| 1   || 2   ||  
|| 1   || 3   ||
|| 2   || 3   ||
|| 3   || 1   ||
|| 2   || 1   ||
================
```

If I choose 1 in my query the result should be:

```
================
|| a   || b   ||
=======||=======
|| 1   || 2   ||  
|| 1   || 3   ||
================
```

This table is a result of selecting the rows which has a=1 or b=1 and do not repeat a,b or the inverse. 
**Details:**

The result of `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a=1 OR b=1;` will be:

```
================
|| a   || b   ||
=======||=======
|| 1   || 2   ||  
|| 1   || 3   ||
|| 3   || 1   ||
|| 2   || 1   ||
================
```

I should eliminate the repeated rows normally and inversely.

`|| 2   || 1   ||` will be eliminated because it's the inverse of `|| 1   || 2   ||`

`|| 3   || 1   ||` will be eliminated because it's the inverse of `|| 1   || 3   ||`

The result was shown above.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: `select distinct least(a,b), greatest(a,b) from the_table`

Answer (score 4):

A more efficient (and somewhat shorter) version of what Jon of All Trades mentioned [in his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/131747/39384) could be something like this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
CASE WHEN A < B THEN A ELSE B END AS value1,
CASE WHEN A < B THEN B ELSE A END AS value2
FROM T
```

Of course if you had to only check for tuples that contain `1`, you would add something like `WHERE A = 1 OR B = 1`

Comment: This has another benefit: no risk of collision with the separator.  If A and B are text values, some edge cases like "A|" + "" and "A" + "|" would be treated the same, whereas in your case they're always separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

So the outputs should be { 1, 2 } and { 1, 3 }?  I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it, but if you just need a quick-and-dirty solution, this should work for you on SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    LEFT(Concatenated, CHARINDEX('|', Concatenated) - 1),
    SUBSTRING(Concatenated, CHARINDEX('|', Concatenated) + 1, 999)
FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE 
            WHEN A < B 
            THEN CAST(A AS VARCHAR(10)) + '|' + CAST(B AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            ELSE CAST(B AS VARCHAR(10)) + '|' + CAST(A AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        END AS Concatenated
    FROM
        T
    WHERE
        A = 1 OR B = 1
    ) AS X
```

Comment: Thank you. 
give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.